# Paypal sandbox downtime Unable to complete request and asking to try again shortly

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, sandbox

Trying to login to paypal sandbox but its giving me 'try again later' message.
do you know if its downtime or something like that?

Exact message : We're unable to complete your request. Please try again shortly.

Thanks
Janki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got reply on twitter by Paypal that it was down for half a day and now up.

This is sorted now, it was issue on Paypal Sandbox.

Thanks
Janki

Answer (score 0):

I think so as I tried logging in here
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com and it took like 2 min to load; didn't timeout though. Besides the cache/cookie obvious; try clearing out the java cache data in the java of the control panel and try a different browser to see.

you can try resetting the password of the login you're trying @ developer.paypal.com; see if that works.

Worse case you can wait, or submit a ticket at paypal.com/mts / contact support.